# Could not parse mapping document from resource student.hbm.xml Exception in HIbernate

Tags: hibernate

I am getting the following exception in hibernate

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource student.hbm.xml
```

i had done every thing correct as of my knowledge..But still it is showing exception.. Below is the following code.Please help me regarding this

**student.hbm.xml**

this is mapping xml file

```
     <hibernate-mapping>  
      <class name="com.Student" table="student">  
       <id name="id" type="int" column="sid">
         <generator class="assigned"/>
      </id>
      <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string"/>

      </class>  

     </hibernate-mapping>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**
This is the confiuration xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
       <session-factory>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect">
          org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
       </property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
          com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  
       </property>

       <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
       <property name="hibernate.connection.url"> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test

       </property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
          root
       </property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
          root
       </property>

       <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
       <mapping resource="student.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

This is Student Bean class 
**Bean class: Student.java**
    package com;

```
public class Student {
    private int id;  
    private String firstName,lastName;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    } 
}
```

**Test class: Storedata.java**
This is Testing  class to store data in to db
    package com;

```
import org.hibernate.Session;  
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;  
import org.hibernate.Transaction;  
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration; 
public class Storedata {

    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        //creating configuration object  
        Configuration cfg=new Configuration();  
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");//populates the data of the configuration file  


        SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();  

        //creating session object  
        Session session=factory.openSession();  

        //creating transaction object  
        Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();  

        Student e1=new Student();  
       // e1.setId(115);  
        e1.setFirstName("Kiran"); 
        e1.setLastName("raj");  

        session.save(e1);
            t.commit();//transaction is committed  
        session.close();  

        System.out.println("successfully saved");  

    } 


}
```

The above code is giving follwoing excepion

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource student.hbm.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:569)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1584)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1552)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1531)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1505)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at com.Storedata.main(Storedata.java:13)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:566)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection reset Nested exception: Connection reset
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:499)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: is `student.hbm.xml` in the same folder as `hibernate.cfg.xml`?

Comment: @Apostolos:::   THank you......  Yes both xmls are in same folder,,, Actually it is worked yesterday but today when i tried to do some operation it is showing that exception...

Comment: AFter 24 hours again i run the same appliation then it was working fine...I could nt find why it was showing that exception on that day....